# Altering the anchor text of main navigation links

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm looking for a way to edit the anchor text used for the links in my store's main navigation menu.

The reason for this is I'm looking to rename some categories to be more SEO-friendly, but this makes them quite long and meandering. For example, I want my "Women's" category to now be called "Women's fashion, clothes and shoes" but would like the link in the main navigation to remain "women's".

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Magento has an attribute for categories called **`URL Key`**, which is set by magento if you leave it blank.

[image: category edit page]

If you want the URL to be old one even if you change category name, then do not make any change in field **`URL Key`**.

Just change name of category and save it.

You can change URL key any time if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mohit. The problem I'm having is not the URL, it's the category name. I basically want a category to have two names - one full name used on the page itself, and one for just use in the menu. Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: To do that, you will need to add custom category attribute and then make some changes in phtml file to use that attribute's value in frontend.

Comment: To know how to add custom category attribute, visit:

https://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/

or

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/